# download video and store it in iphone local folder

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to download video on internet & store it in iphone local folder.

Please any suggestion or link information or tutorial give me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a jailbroken iPhone then [mxtube](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.mxweas.mxtube) is pretty good app for that.